# Converting Surface_mesh to Nef_polyhedron_3

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to use CGAL to do some boolean operations on meshes.

How do I convert from Surface_mesh to Nef_polyhedron_3?

**EDIT:**
I've tried with this code, but I don't know how to continue...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>

using namespace std;

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<K::Point_3> Mesh;

int main()
{
    Mesh m;
    auto a = m.add_vertex(K::Point_3(0,0,0));
    auto b = m.add_vertex(K::Point_3(0,0,0));
    auto c = m.add_vertex(K::Point_3(0,0,0));
    m.add_face(a,b,c);

    Mesh::Halfedge_range range = m.halfedges();
    for(Mesh::Halfedge_index hei : range)
    {
        // ??? <<--
        std::cout << hei << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your trials please. We're not here to do the work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the suggested way to do this is to use the 3d polyhedral surface package instead. The [Nef 3 documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html#title8) describes the conversion between Polyhedron_3 and Nef_3. The only difference between the 3d polyhedral surface package and the surface mesh package is that, it is pointer based rather than index based.

Comment: After I've created the Polyhedron, if I convert it to a NefPolyhedron with `CGAL::NefPolyhedron(p);` it crashes here: `CGAL_error_msg( "it is not possible to decide which one is a visible facet (if any)");`...

How can I solve?
Thanks.

Comment: Not every Polyhedron can be converted to a nef polyhedron. E.g. the polyhedron has to be closed and can't be self intersecting. What polyhedron are you trying to convert?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a Polyhedron which is imported from a different 3d object (not CGAL) and is closed... 

This is an excerpt of my code:
https://gist.github.com/tesfabpel/68d1c1fd61c6d9aae904

I may be missing something, but I don't know (I'm a beginner in CGAL, but I need it for its 3D Boolean Operations on Nef Polyhedra)

Comment: It seems that your mesh builder adds each vertex once for each triangle it is included in. Thus, it results in a collection of separate triangles rather than a coherent mesh. Imagine if you have a simple tetrahedron. Your builder would 12 vertices although only 4 is needed. I am not sure, but i highly doubt that CGAL will automatically stitch your mesh together. I would split the mesh creation into two for loops. One adding vertices, and one adding the triangles. Additionally, in a closed triangular mesh, the number of halfedges will always be exactly 3*number of triangles.